# Recover .vdi file with Scalpel (or anything similar)

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, gparted

I want to recover a 45 Gig .vdi file. *I did not delete it.*

I was resizing (expanding) my external harddrive partition (some 420 Gig to add some extra 40 Gig) on which many including the .vdi file was on, using GParted.

For [whatever reason(s), beyond my understanding](http://pastebin.com/cRqWxfS4) (a path I don't wanna go down on right now, considering how highly unreliable Ubuntu has become in recent years), Ubuntu restarted.

After restart, the specific partition was inaccessible. Obviously, things have moved around but couldn't finished. I lost everything on that partition.

Using scalpel, to recover for instance, a PDF file, something like this should be in the `/etc/scalpel/scalpel.conf` file:

```
# ADOBE PDF
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#       pdf     y       5000000 %PDF  %EOF\x0d  REVERSE
#       pdf     y       5000000 %PDF  %EOF\x0a  REVERSE
```

I simply have to uncomment the above `pdf` lines to get the recovery to happen in looking for pdf files.

For `.vdi` files, what do I put in those second, third, fourth and fifth columns?

What's more:

- is there a possibility of getting the .vdi file back in one piece, at a usable state?
- do I stand a better chance using other data recovery?

Comment: @Takkat perhaps you didn't finish reading my question before slapping with the duplicate thing. The .vdi file was NOT deleted. The partition on which the .vdi was on, was rendered useless. I want to recover all the vdi files on the external using Scalpel.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I retracted my close vote but the procedures for recovery a VDI file with testdisk are not much different only that you use an image of your partition instead of a VDI file.  In case you can't see the VDI files with testdisk you  can try with PhotoRec. AFAIK Scalpel does not support VDI without a custom .conf.

Comment: @Takkat and it is *that* custom .conf that I wish to populate with the encoding whatever code for .vdi files.